# ssdeep's fuzzy_compare always returns 0 loaded from ctypes python

Tags: python, ctypes

Having a problem with getting the fuzzy_compare function to return a proper comparison value. It should be returning 0~100 but always returns 0.

```
from ctypes import *
fuzzy = CDLL('fuzzy.dll')
out1 = create_string_buffer('\x00'*512)
out2 = create_string_buffer('\x00'*512)
print fuzzy.fuzzy_hash_buf('hashme', len('hashme'), out1)
print fuzzy.fuzzy_hash_buf('hashme2', len('hashme2'), out2)
print out1.value
print out2.value
print fuzzy.fuzzy_compare(out1, out2)
# output
#    0
#    0
#    3:cA:x <-- correct hash
#    3:cy:R <-- correct hash
#    0      <-- fuzzy_compare returning 0...
```

I've tried calling fuzzy compare with out1.value, casting to c_char_p() and create_string_buffer() but it always returns 0. I've looked at it in a debugger (set a bp on the fuzzy_compare function and it's passing the values correctly, i just have no idea why it always returns 0. Am I using the function incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled the included `sample.c`, and it seemed to work. So I tried something similar in Python. Note that it uses a very large input buffer (0x50000) and only modifies 16 bytes, yielding a close match of 99.

```
import ctypes
from random import randrange, seed

seed(42)

SPAMSUM_LENGTH = 64
FUZZY_MAX_RESULT = SPAMSUM_LENGTH + SPAMSUM_LENGTH // 2 + 20
SIZE = 0x50000

fuzzy = ctypes.CDLL('fuzzy.dll')

fuzzy_hash_buf = fuzzy.fuzzy_hash_buf
fuzzy_hash_buf.restype = ctypes.c_int
fuzzy_hash_buf.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_char_p, #buf
    ctypes.c_uint32, #buf_len
    ctypes.c_char_p, #result
]
fuzzy_compare = fuzzy.fuzzy_compare
fuzzy_compare.restype = ctypes.c_int
fuzzy_compare.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_char_p, #sig1
    ctypes.c_char_p, #sig2
]

out1 = ctypes.create_string_buffer('\x00' * FUZZY_MAX_RESULT)
out2 = ctypes.create_string_buffer('\x00' * FUZZY_MAX_RESULT)

in1 = ''.join(chr(randrange(256)) for x in xrange(SIZE))
in2 = ''.join(c if (i < 0x100 or i >= 0x110) else '\x25'
              for i, c in enumerate(in1))

print fuzzy_hash_buf(in1, len(in1), out1)
print fuzzy_hash_buf(in2, len(in2), out2)
print out1.value
print out2.value
print fuzzy_compare(out1, out2)
```

Output:

```
0
0
6144:rR1yoHH0XI3VFNdCRXmg0BqMFKDLA6sPaVujZAQhO5HQXNHtQyr4zgytywlfj:qYFF5CRXmg9IK4ouqQAHu+y8zgS7
6144:LR1yoHH0XI3VFNdCRXmg0BqMFKDLA6sPaVujZAQhO5HQXNHtQyr4zgytywlfj:KYFF5CRXmg9IK4ouqQAHu+y8zgS7
99
```

Comment: you are my hero. works like a charm, guess i should study up on how the hell ctypes works!